# Создание папок в Android 10

Tags: android, android-scoped-storage

У меня появилась проблема при создании папок. Мне необходимо создать папку в зависимости от доступного положения. Данный код работает на Android ниже 10, но не работает выше

```
            if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                mainFolder = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "MyApp");
            } else {
                mainFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyApp");
            }

            if (!mainFolder.exists()) {
                mainFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            File audio = new File(mainFolder, "Audios");
            audio.mkdirs();
            setAudioFolder(audio.getPath());
```

При том, что у меня в AndroidManifest.xml указан параметр, который должен позволять сохранять на внутреннюю память

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        <!-- -->
    </application>
```

Пробовал искать решения данной проблемы, но ничего из найденного не помогает. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Без логов и информации о `targetSdk` попытаюсь ткнуть пальцем в небо и угадать.

[Вот тут пишут](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#privacy), что

> Android 11 introduces changes and restrictions to enhance user privacy, including the following:
>
> - Scoped storage enforcement: Access into external storage directories is limited to an app-specific directory and specific types of media
>   that the app has created.

[А вот тут уточняют](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage), что

> Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

Если коротко, то как только вы перешли на `targetSdk 30`, костыль `requestLegacyExternalStorage` на `Android 11` больше не работает.

Время переходить на `scoped storage`.